# Can a memcache page change slab class?

Tags: memcached

I'm trying to understand how memcached memory model works.

**If all items in an assigned page have expired or been deleted, can that page be marked as unassigned (and later migrate to another slab class)?** That is, let's say I fill up  my memcached instance with lots of 1 kb objects with an expiry of 24 hours. 48 hours later, I write lots of 512 kb items (different slab class), will the 1 kb slab class pages slowly get unassigned?

If this is the case, best practise should be to always set an expiry time for all objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some tests on 1.4.20 (starting the app without any flags) and can confirm that within the ~5 minutes I ran the tests, pages did not change slab classes.

Above said, there is something called [`automover`](https://github.com/memcached/memcached/wiki/ReleaseNotes1425#new-features) which is a background thread that automatically can change the slab class for pages as they turn unused.